# Recostruct image from K space

Tags: image-processing, filter, signals, fft, frequency

In all tutorials there is an image and after applying FFT ,we get the image in frequecy domain.And by following the inverse procedure we reconstruct the original image.
But what if we start with unknown jpg of a fourier transform(In K space of MRI for example).I can not inverse the step in pseudocode:

```
fourier_image=log(abs(ffshift(fft(original_image))))
```

and go back.

Comment: why is your inner most api call fft shouldn't it be inverse_fft ?

Comment: This is the code for geting the Fourier transform. I want to inverse this line of code!